# Laravel Modules and dynamic menus

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 with `nWidart/laravel-modules`.
My problem is how populate sidebar menu with entries that comes from modules? For example, Wordpress plugins can register custom menu entries.

What is the best way to archieve this? View composers (with service providers) and scan for modules each render and call... exactly, where I should put functions in module to return menu entries that this module want to register?